# Values of quadratic form on unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

We have the quadratic form $q(\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix})=11x^2-16xy-y^2$.

> Which values does $q$ take on the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$?

I know that $q(x,y)$ is given by $q(x,y)=(x,y)\begin{pmatrix}11&-8\\-8&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ and that $\begin{pmatrix}11&-8\\-8&-1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}-2&-1\\1&-2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}15&0\\0&-5\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}-2&-1\\1&-2\end{pmatrix}^T$. But I don't know how I could use this further.

Comment: Hint: try to use the substitution $x=\cos \theta$ and $y=\sin \theta$

Comment: @JosephCurwen Then I get $q=11\cos^2t-16\cos t\sin t-\sin ^2t$, what can I do with that?

Comment: @BobdeBouwer - now use the cosine and sine double angle formulas to convert everything to a double angle. Then you have a choice of finding the right angle to add to combine the elements to a single cosine or sine, or you just differentiate and find the maximum and minimum. (Or you can apply the method of Lagrange multipliers to the original form to find the maximum and minimum.)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Would you mind showing me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Joseph Curwen's hint: 
$$\begin{align}q &= 11\cos^2\theta-16\cos \theta\sin \theta-\sin ^2\theta\\
&=12\cos^2\theta-16\cos \theta\sin \theta-1\end{align}$$
Now $$\sin 2\theta = 2\cos\theta\sin\theta\\\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2 \theta - 1$$
So,
$$\begin{align}q &= 6\cos 2\theta - 8\sin 2\theta + 5\\&=6\cos t - 8\sin t + 5\end{align}$$
Where $t = 2\theta$ (since $\theta$ was arbitrary, there is no reason to stick with it). Now set $q' = 0$ and find the maximum and minimum values of $q$. Since $q$ is continuous, it will take on every value between them.

Comment: As an added suggestion: learn those trig formulas! Angle sum and difference formulas for sine and cosine, and the double angle formulas above, and the other two double angle formulas for cosine. It is well worth the effort. They are *extremely* useful.